# How to default a table column value with text and auto generated numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create sequence test_sq;
create sequence test_sq1;

create table test
(
    col1 number default test_sq.nextval,
    col2 number default lpad('req-'||test_sq1.nextval,5,'0'),
    col3 varchar2(20)
);
```

I need to create a table for which `col1` and `col2` columns should be as per below

- `col1` should be auto generated - I will use `test_sq.nextval` for this
- `col2` should be auto generated with the format `REQ-00001` and this column will have 5 digits only starting from `REQ-`. Like `REQ-00001`, `REQ-00002`,... , `REQ-00025` etc

How can I achieve this?

DB Version: Oracle 19c

Comment: what oracle version are you using?

Comment: @Sund'er Oracle 19c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, not like that. `col1` should then be an identity column (so you'd let Oracle create & use sequence it creates *in the background*. For `col2`, create a trigger.

Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE test_sq1;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     col1   NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4     col2   VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     col3   VARCHAR2 (20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_test
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON test
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     :new.col2 := 'req-' || LPAD (test_sq1.NEXTVAL, 5, '0');
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test (col3) VALUES ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test (col3) VALUES ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

      COL1 COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 req-00001  Little
         2 req-00002  Foot

SQL>
```

---

If you'd still like to use your own sequence for `col1`, you can - don't generate it as identity and add yet another line into the trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE test_sq;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE test_sq1;

Sequence created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     col1   NUMBER,
  4     col2   VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     col3   VARCHAR2 (20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_bi_test
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON test
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     :new.col1 := test_sq.NEXTVAL;
  7     :new.col2 := 'req-' || LPAD (test_sq1.NEXTVAL, 5, '0');
  8  END;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test (col3) VALUES ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test (col3) VALUES ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

      COL1 COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1 req-00001  Little
         2 req-00002  Foot

SQL>
```

---

Without a trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     col1   NUMBER DEFAULT test_sq.NEXTVAL,
  4     col2   VARCHAR2 (30) DEFAULT 'req-' || LPAD (test_sq1.NEXTVAL, 5, '0'),
  5     col3   VARCHAR2 (20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test (col3) VALUES ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO test (col3) VALUES ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

      COL1 COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- --------------------
         8 req-00008  Little
         9 req-00009  Foot

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for this but can we do this without using triggers?

Comment: Apparently, yes - see edited answer.

Comment: @Littlefloot thanks for this. Actually I was using number datatype hence it was not working :( And can I use only one sequence instead of creating two?

Comment: Of course, no need for two sequences. Just beware! What will you do once sequence hits 99999?